# Replace elements in list from element with value to end with new list

Tags: c++, stl

I have path in board like list of pairs of indexes like

```
list<pair<int,int> > *path;
```

When character reaches obstacle I need to replace in path all from current position to end with new path but to save path from start to obstacle same ( to clarify a little character has start and destination cell and moves from start to destination and back and repeat again same. To avoid lot off calculation I would try to save part of path without obstacle and just replace old part with new from obstacle to end).
Is there easy way to do this without iterating ?

Edited later to clarify:
path old is [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)] and obstacle is on cell (1,2) so character goes [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1)] searches for new path which is for example [(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(1,3),(1,4)] so I need to replace from old path (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4) with (1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(1,3),(1,4)

Comment: I'm curious why you made `path` a pointer to list, rather than a list?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why is it a problem (when you hit an obstacle, your path arrives at the obstacle, simply go back one step and try again) ? I vaguely feel like you are looking for `std::list::splice`, but it's hard to tell from your question.

Comment: @us2012 I added what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly: You have a list `path` from `start` to `destination`, which hits an obstacle somewhere in the middle  (you have to know where, so let's say you have a valid `list<...>::iterator obstacle` that points to the obstacle). You also have a `newpath` going from `*(obstacle - 1)` to `destination`, and you want to cut and paste those two paths together. This is how you could do it (I'm assuming `list`s instead of  `list*`s here, but if you really need that you can easily rewrite it to work with the pointer):

```
//kill the wrong bit of the old path
path.erase(obstacle, path.end());
//append the correct newpath
path.splice(path.end(), newpath, newpath.begin(), newpath.end());
```

Note that `newpath` is empty after this operation.